# How to constraint a child view controller's view to the tab bar's top anchor?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[image]

In the picture above I am trying to create a feature that can search through the Yelp APIs for a specific business. This child view view controller has a table view inside of it.

I add the child view controller to its parent using the following code:

```
func addChildBusinessSearchController(){

        businessSearchResultController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessSearchResultController") as! BusinessSearchResultController
        businessSearchResultController.delegate = self
        businessSearchResultController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext


        view.addSubview(businessSearchResultController.view)
        self.addChildViewController(businessSearchResultController)
        businessSearchResultController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        businessSearchResultController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let heightConstraint = businessSearchResultController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.bounds.height)
        let leadingConstraint = businessSearchResultController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
        let widthConstraint = businessSearchResultController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.bounds.width)
        let topViewUpperConstraint = businessSearchResultController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -55)
        topViewUpperConstraint.identifier = ChildControllersUpperConstraints.businessSearchResultControllerTopConstraintIdentifier

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint, leadingConstraint, widthConstraint, topViewUpperConstraint])

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(businessSearchResultControllerdidPan(_:)))


        businessSearchResultController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

 }
```

Within the child controller I try to constraint the table view so that is shows up on the screen with the correct dimensions:

```
   func setUpTableView(){

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let topConstraint = tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor)
        let leadingConstraint = tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingConstraint = tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        let heightConstraint = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, heightConstraint])
        tableView.clipsToBounds = true
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 }
```

However, I have one problem: I seem to be having trouble constraining the bottom of the table view in "BusinessSearchResultController" to the top of the tab bar so that it fills all the space intended for the this table view. I understand that this is because I am giving it a non-dynamic height of 450 in the following code:

`let heightConstraint = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)`

But I have tried different ways to achieve the correct height for this table view including constraining its `bottomAnchor` to the `topAnchor` of its parent `bottomLayoutGuide` which of course results in an error because they don't have a common ancestor.

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated...

Comment: Is the tab bar visible at all times? This might be a kludge, but maybe you could pass a CGRect (or `UIView`) into `setUpTableView` based on the "safe area" of the search result controller. Once you have that, create a "clear" subview and constrain your table view to it.

Comment: Yes the tab bar is visible for the entire life cycle of the search result controller @dfd

Comment: That's the... requirement I guess for my proposal. Sounds like you have a static CGRect you need to define for the table view. Again, it's not elegant - yep, a kludge - but constraints need a view hierarchy and well, maybe this gets you that.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view is a subview of your `BusinessSearchResultController`.

You don't want a **height** constraint on your table view, you want to constrain the bottom of the  table view to the bottom of its superview -- the same way you are setting its leading and trailing constraints.

Then, constrain the bottom of `businessSearchResultController.view` to the bottom of *its* superview, the same way your are setting *its* leading and trailing constraints.